# Can a multiclassed barbarian/cleric use their Channel Divinity while raging?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, multi-classing, barbarian, rage

My question has to do with a multiclass of Barbarian and Cleric. If you have the necessary levels of both classes, can you use your Channel Divinity while you are raging?

The barbarian's [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#Rage) feature states:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can't cast them or concentrate on them while raging

Channel Divinity doesn't state that it is a spell, just an action, as seen in the [Life Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#LifeDomain)'s Preserve Life option:

> As an action, you present your holy symbol and evoke healing energy that can restore a number of hit points points equal to five times your cleric level.

Can a multiclassed barbarian/cleric use their Channel Divinity while raging?

Comment: Note: not all Channel Divinity options take your action to use. Some apply when you or someone else attacks, some when an attack is made, some when damage is rolled, and one takes an hour to do.

Comment: Just pulled this one as an example of a single action Channel Divinity, I am mainly concerned that it was considered a spell even though it wasn't explicitly stated as one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes, they can use a Channel Divinity option while raging.

As you've noted, Channel Divinity is not a spell. Rage only prevents casting a spell or concentrating on one. As such, raging does not prevent you from using your Channel Divinity in any way...

But keep in mind that your rage will end "if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then" - so if you haven't already gotten hit (and taken damage) since your last turn ended, a Channel Divinity option that uses up your action may not be the best use of your action.

Comment: Main idea is the final round of the rage to use this end it and take full advantage of rage beyond death without actually dying. However as a side note that issue is also fixed at barbarian 15 with Relentless Rage.